# Best way to handle the dismissal of website alerts/notifications (and keep track of state using cookies)

Tags: javascript, cookies

Our website may have multiple alerts/notifications that appears at the top. The likelihood of having more than one is pretty small, but in the event that needs to occur, I'd like to be able to track the state of the notification based on the user action. If the user doesn't dismiss it, I'd like it to continue to display. If they do dismiss it, I'd like for that to persist through their current session on the site.

I'm able to set and get a cookie to verify whether or not someone has dismissed a single alert, but I'm not sure how to handle multiple. Since there could be an unlimited amount of notifications/alerts (unrealistic, but I need to keep track of an undetermined amount), I'm not entirely sure what direction I should go. I'm currently handling all of this via JS/jQuery, without the jQuery cookie plugin (I won't be using that in this solution either). Any help it appreciated.

Comment: So you give them ids and store the viewed ones into an array....

Comment: @jesseearley do you use the notifications API ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API

Comment: @epascarello and save the array into a cookie? How does an array persist across the site?

Comment: Um in the cookie?

Comment: JSON stringify and parse.